# Browser returns error 404 when command `dotnet run` is entered

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm having some issues with .NETCore, I'm making a simple WebApi for college, but whenever I run `dotnet run` command on my Windows terminal I get the following output:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\recru\source\repos\prova-dotnetcore\WebApi
```

But on my browser I get the error 404. Please help me. This is my Startup.cs:

```
using Application.Context;
using Application.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;
using System;


namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<ProvaContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("ProvaDoubleIt"));
            services.AddTransient<IProdutoService, ProdutoService>();
            services.AddTransient<ICategoriaService, CategoriaService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
            services.AddControllers();

            // Add authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var issuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
                var audience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
                var key = Configuration["Jwt:Key"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(issuer))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(issuer));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(audience))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(audience));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
                }

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    ValidAudience = audience,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
                };
            });

            // Add Swagger
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API da Prova DotNetCore", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. 
                          Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                          Example: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                },
                Array.Empty<string>()
            }
        });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

    }
}
```

This is a simple Login route on my controller:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Application.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public UserController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            var result = await _usuarioService.DoLogin(email, password);

            if (result == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Email or password incorrect");
            }

            return Ok("User logged in!.");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the WebApi.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <StartupObject>WebApi.Program</StartupObject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[This is my "C:\Program Files\dotnet" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIhDI.png)

Please help me! Thanks a Lot everyone, let me know if you need any more information about my project!

Comment: What is the url in the browser? Have you tried hitting F5? Have you tried calling a valid url (POST to `/user/login`)? Check [launchsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) file, it may contain url which is opened in the browser - fix it to a correct one.

Comment: So the link in my Browser is http://localhost:5000/, my [launchsettings.json](https://jsfiddle.net/dcwnxzm5/) for u to check it out, I will try http://localhost/user/login to see if anything changes.

Comment: See my comments for similar issue earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976934/how-to-access-the-controller-function-with-httpget#comment134002673_75976934

Comment: So the `launchBrowser` is set to true - this makes the `dotnet run` to open browser at start. `applicationUrl` controls the url which browser is opened on. Since you have only one controller with one action and it is a POST one I would suggest just to set `launchBrowser` to false.

Comment: @jdweng I used this code on my Startup.cs `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "api/{controller}");
            });` I'm using .NETCore 3.1.32 requested by my college professor, I'm still on error 404

Comment: @GuruStron I changed what u told me on launchsettings.json and when I run `dotnet run` And show the Debug output on Visual Studio I see the folloing message:

"The program  "[6612] WebApi.exe" was closed by code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

Comment: The route and filenames have to be consistent in the config file.  My link explains the relationship between files and route.  This doesn't change between different Net/Core versions.

Comment: Interesting. Then return everything back and change the url to a valid GET one. Swagger UI can be a good candidate.

Comment: I did it, but no luck. :( Still on 404 err, bu when I try to access localhost:57239 (which is the Application with the services) I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: If anyone wants to try it for yourself I just created a repository on GitHub: https://github.com/lbombassei/.NET-WebApi please let me know if u guys found anything!

Comment: Hey guys, just updating here! The server is running, I tried to use postman and I got a response from the server side, now, my only problem is making swagger right... Can't seem to make it work, it is a requirement that Swagger be implemented and documented in my WebApi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to update everyone, I got everything on the works now, including Swagger using the following code

```
 app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API da Prova DotNetCore");
                });
```

Thanks for your help, it gave somewhere to begin on solving my issues on this code!